# Ignore gif files from ImageResizer

Tags: c#, image-resizing, imageresizer

We use [ImageResizer](https://imageresizing.net/) Performance Edition to resize our images in our portals and it works just fine except with **gif** files. We have enabled the [AnimatedGifs](https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/animatedgifs) plugin, but the images got way bigger than the original size which seems to be a known issue.

So we got rid of the [AnimatedGifs](https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/animatedgifs) plugin and as a workaround we bypass any image file from ImageResizer if it has the **gif** extension, for example:

```cs
if (imgExtension != ".gif") {
   // add image resizer params ?width=xxx&height=xxx...
}
```

Is there some other way to solve this with configuration instead of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inageflow .NET Server (The .NET Core version of ImageResizer) produces much smalller animated GIFs than ImageResizer and does so much faster. I would consider switching to this newer project if animated gifs are important to you.

If you have an ImageResizer subscription then Imageflow is included.

Comment: We plan to upgrade to Imageflow in a near future.